# why is the chance that $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is divisibile by $7$ when $a, b, c$ are positive integers equal to $1/7$?

Tags: probability-theory, number-theory

Modulo $7$, any square is congruent to $0,1,2,$ or $4$.  If one forms all possible sums of three residues and throws out repetitions (i.e., $001$ and $044$ both are congruent to $1$ modulo $7$) I obtain $20$ distinct sums: $3$ are congruent to $1, 3$ are congruent to $2, ..., 3$ are congruent to $6$, and TWO ($000$ and $124$) are congruent to $7$ or $0$ modulo $7$.  Thus I obtain TWO favorable cases out of the twenty possible cases and the probability is $\frac{2}{20}=\frac{1}{10}$ which is not $\frac{1}{7}$.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: The 20 cases you’ve listed aren’t equally likely.

Comment: Also, as an aside, it isn’t actually possible to pick even a single random natural number or integer uniformly. So you really should restrict the question to picking $a,b,c$ uniformly and independently from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Comment: In the United States the paper currency denominations are $1,2,5,10,20,50,100$. There are $7$ of them. So if I gather all of the paper money into a giant room and pull out one bill at random, is the chance that it is a $\$1$ bill $\frac17$? Is the chance that it is a $\$50$ bill $\frac17$?

Answer (score 1):

There are $7^3$ combinations of residue modulo $7$ for $a$, $b$, $c$.  (That is, three independent selections from the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.)

Of those, $49$ satisfy $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ congruent to $0$ modulo $7$.  They are
$$ (a,b,c) \in \{ (0,0,0), (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,2), \\ \dots, (6,4,2), (6,4,5), (6,5,4)\} $$

At the very least, in your argument, there is only one residue that squares to $0$ and two residues squaring to each of $1$, $2$, and $4$, so treating these four squares as equally likely is an error.  That is, there is only one set of residues whose squares are your $(0,0,0)$, but there are eight whose squares are your $(1,2,4)$.  It's also not entirely clear in your writing that you have accounted for permutations.  There is only one permutation of $(0,0,0)$, but there are six of $(1,2,4)$.  So the $49$ ways to get $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ congruent to zero have one way giving the squares $(0,0,0)$ and $6 \cdot 8$ ways to get the squares $(1,2,4)$.

Comment: Yes, I see that my error was treating combinations such as (0,0,0) and (1,2,4) as equally likely.  So the probability is (1+6x8)/7^3=1/7...very nice...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\hline n^{2} \bmod 7 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}

By the table, we can observe that $(a,b,c)$ are either the permutations of $(1,2,4) $or $(0,0,0) $ and hence

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\quad \displaystyle  P\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \equiv 0(\bmod 7)\right) \\\displaystyle 
=\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{2}{7}+\frac{1}{7} \times \frac{1}{7} \times \frac{1}{7} \\
=\displaystyle \frac{1}{7}
\end{array}
$$